# ubuntu 20.04 LTS driver intel WI-FI 6E AX211 160MHZ

Tags: drivers, 20.04

After a fresh install of Ubuntu on my new Lenovo Legion Y9000P 2022，I'm unable to use Wi-Fi or Bluetooth，or even the touch tablet of the PC. My Wi-Fi model is Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHZ.

Can anyone help me? I'll appreciate you so much!

Comment: Looking at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi it shows that the AX211 is supported in Kernel 5.14, so unfortunately the support in even the HWE Kernels for 20.04 LTS are not there.  You can upgrade to 21.10 or wait until 22.04 LTS comes out in April as it will be using 5.15 Kernel version.  Or unless the AX210 version works for you now.

Comment: I had a similar problem with an AX211 adapter in Kali / Debian linux where the latest linux-firmware is from half a year ago (?!). I would think providing up-to-date drivers is one of the higher priorities of a distro. Anyway, eventually found this repository, which provides up-to-date firmware in a .deb package: https://github.com/q3aql/drivers-linux-firmware Make sure you follow the instructions on the page to get things copied in the proper place.

Answer (score 2):

I have exact same wifi module on my laptop and solved this problem by installing the latest dkms backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu2_all.deb downloaded from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backport-iwlwifi-dkms

check my answer here [No hope for AX211 wifi working on ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402766/no-hope-for-ax211-wifi-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Simply

```
$ sudo dpkg -i backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

and reboot.

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. However only the wifi is working now. Bluetooth is not functioning. Do you have a fix for that too?

Comment: An upgrade to `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` should fix all missing drivers for more recent laptops. More details of LTS hardware support details can be found at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Answer (score 1):

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS, and what worked for me was to just update the Linux kernel to version 5.15 from version 5.13. **Note**: I am assuming that when installing Ubuntu, you installed the third-party software that includes WiFi drivers.

There are two ways to do this:

1. If you have internet access (via an Ethernet to USB adapter for example), just run `sudo apt-get upgrade linux-generic-hwe-20.04` followed by `sudo reboot`. To check that version 5.15 was installed, run `apt list linux-generic-hwe*` and you should see `linux-generic-hwe-20.04/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.15.0.46.49~20.04.16 amd64 [installed]`.
2. If, like me, you do not have internet access, then you will need to install the latest version of the `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` package manually. In my case, I had another laptop that had internet access, so I used that laptop to download the package and its dependencies, put them on a USB, and then moved them to the laptop that does not have internet access.

To do this, first go to [this page](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/kernel/linux-generic-hwe-20.04). You will see the following dependencies:

```
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.15.0.46.49~20.04.16) [amd64]
    Generic Linux kernel headers 
linux-headers-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.4.0.26.32) [not amd64]
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.15.0.46.49~20.04.16) [amd64]
    Generic Linux kernel image 
linux-image-generic-hwe-20.04 (= 5.4.0.26.32) [not amd64]
```

Before installing the package, you will need to install these dependencies first by clicking on their links. In my case, I installed the dependencies that had the label `[amd64]` next to them, since my laptop runs a 64-bit architecture. Unfortunately, these dependencies have their own dependencies, so you will have to click on each one and then download the corresponding `.deb` file. In total there were 7 `.deb` files that I had to download, so this does not take too much time. To download each package, click on the `amd64` link under the `Download <package name>` title. Then, click on the link `security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu`. Once all packages are downloaded, put them all into a folder, and then put this folder onto a USB.

Finally, connect the USB to the laptop with no internet access, move the folder containing the packages to the desktop, `cd` into this folder, and then run `sudo dpkg -i *.deb`. You will get an error that the `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` package could not be installed, but that is OK. Just run `sudo reboot`, and once logged in again, check that you have version 5.15 of the linux kernel by running `uname -r`. You should see `5.15.0-46-generic`. Your WiFi should now be working.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problems with the following setup:
+CPU: Intel core i7 13700H 
+GPU: Nvidia GeForce GTX 1650 
+Bluetooth-wireless: Gigabit Lan & Wireless intel @ Wi-Fi 6E AX211

The solution was to update Ubuntu to version 23.04, which also included the latest kernel. Despite trying multiple solutions and reading through numerous posts, I couldn't find any effective remedies. In my case, I also struggled with Nvidia drivers and issues related to suspend/resume functionality. If you're dealing with similar headaches, opting to install version 23.04 might just be the comprehensive solution you need. Choose "Third Party" options during the Ubuntu installation, and everything will work correctly after rebooting.