# No hope for AX211 wifi working on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi, dkms

I fresh installed ubuntu 20.04 on my laptop and apt update & upgraded to the latest.

```
$ uname -r
5.13.0-39-generic
```

So far BT is working fine but only wifi isn't working now.
I checked as below

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    DeviceName: Onboard - Ethernet
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0094]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Network adapter shows UNCLAIMED

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for khyou: 
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:622f284000-622f287fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8125 2.5GbE Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:2c:00.0
       logical name: enp44s0
       version: 05
       serial: 50:eb:f6:d1:4b:1d
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.13.0-39-generic firmware=rtl8125b-2_0.0.2 07/13/20 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:60200000-6020ffff memory:60210000-60213fff
```

Per the answer from here [Wireless Network not showing with iwlwifi card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1401173/wireless-network-not-showing-with-iwlwifi-card)

I downloaded backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9340-0ubuntu4_all.deb from https://packages.ubuntu.com/impish/backport-iwlwifi-dkms

and downloaded linux-firmware-20220310.tar.gz from
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/

### dkms_9340 install

Installed dkms_9340 as below

```
$ sudo dpkg -i backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9340-0ubuntu4_all.deb
Selecting previously unselected package backport-iwlwifi-dkms.
(Reading database ... 185839 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9340-0ubuntu4_all.deb ...
Unpacking backport-iwlwifi-dkms (9340-0ubuntu4) ...
Setting up backport-iwlwifi-dkms (9340-0ubuntu4) ...
Loading new backport-iwlwifi-9340 DKMS files...
Building for 5.13.0-39-generic
Building initial module for 5.13.0-39-generic
Secure Boot not enabled on this system.
Done.

compat.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/

iwlwifi.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/

iwlxvt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/

iwlmvm.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/

mac80211.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/

cfg80211.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/5.13.0-39-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod...

DKMS: install completed.
```

### Copy iwlwifi-so files

And copied all the iwlwifi-so-a0-* files from linux-firmware-20220310

```
$ sudo cp iwlwifi-so-a0-* /lib/firmware
```

### AFTER REBOOT

After reboot, it looks like the wifi module is claimed but not working

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for khyou: 
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: iomemory:620-61f irq:16 memory:622f284000-622f287fff
```

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.014622] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    2.014623] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9340:55438a77
[    2.073131] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.088226] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    2.088243] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.34
[    2.088570] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 67.8f59b80b.0 so-a0-gf-a0-67.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.238949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6E AX211 160MHz, REV=0x370
[    2.245368] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 1, ret=-1
[    2.245371] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 2, ret=-1
[    2.245372] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Failed to set DRAM buffer for alloc id 3, ret=-1
[    2.393431] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x2010d000
[    2.394563] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    2.394664] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    2.394665] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 6
[    2.394667] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Loaded firmware version: 67.8f59b80b.0 so-a0-gf-a0-67.ucode
[    2.394668] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[    2.394670] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000002F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    2.394671] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    2.394672] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D9EF2 | branchlink2
[    2.394673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D01BA | interruptlink1
[    2.394674] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D01BA | interruptlink2
[    2.394675] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D8BF2 | data1
[    2.394676] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000010 | data2
[    2.394677] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | data3
[    2.394678] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    2.394679] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0001265C | tsf low
[    2.394680] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    2.394681] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    2.394682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00024051 | time gp2
[    2.394683] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    2.394684] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000043 | uCode version major
[    2.394685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8F59B80B | uCode version minor
[    2.394686] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000370 | hw version
[    2.394687] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C89002 | board version
[    2.394688] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8007FF05 | hcmd
[    2.394689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    2.394689] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x60000000 | isr1
[    2.394690] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x48F00002 | isr2
[    2.394691] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    2.394692] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    2.394693] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    2.394693] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x004D8BF2 | wait_event
[    2.394694] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    2.394695] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[    2.394696] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    2.394697] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    2.394698] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000000B | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    2.394698] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    2.394699] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000024 | flow_handler
[    2.394746] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    2.394747] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Transport status: 0x0000004A, valid: 7
[    2.394748] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x2010070D | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    2.394749] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    2.394750] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8045E9F6 | umac branchlink2
[    2.394751] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0109712A | umac interruptlink1
[    2.394752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    2.394752] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000005 | umac data1
[    2.394753] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[    2.394754] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[    2.394755] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000043 | umac major
[    2.394756] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8F59B80B | umac minor
[    2.394757] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00024048 | frame pointer
[    2.394757] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xC0885E88 | stack pointer
[    2.394758] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00010C00 | last host cmd
[    2.394759] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    2.394795] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: IML/ROM dump:
[    2.394796] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000B03 | IML/ROM error/state
[    2.394804] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x000071F6 | IML/ROM data1
[    2.394812] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[    2.394818] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    2.394821] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x20000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    2.394823] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x803E0001 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    2.394826] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00190002 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    2.394829] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0000A652 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    2.394832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    2.394835] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    2.394837] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    2.394840] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    2.394843] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00080400 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    2.394848] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00400410 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    2.394852] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00009061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    2.394858] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x00000061 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    2.394920] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[    3.077528] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

According to this answer [ubuntu 20.04 LTS driver intel WI-FI 6E AX211 160MHZ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398392/ubuntu-20-04-lts-driver-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax211-160mhz)

> the AX211 is supported in Kernel 5.14, so unfortunately the support in
> even the HWE Kernels for 20.04 LTS are not there

So there is no hope for ubuntu 20.04 to run AX211 wifi module? or just wait for an update for it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved this problem by installing the latest dkms backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu2_all.deb downloaded from https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backport-iwlwifi-dkms

Simply

```
$ sudo dpkg -i backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu2_all.deb
```

and reboot.
Now wifi is working like charm!

Comment: thank you very much. I installed the backport driver for Jammy Jellyfish and rebooted. It is working. So much thank you.

Comment: Thanks. Solved the same/similar problem I had on my laptop. However, I just did `sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms`. So future people looking for this solution might also just do this as it seems slightly easier to me,