# Wifi adapter not recognised on ubuntu 22.04 on alienware X15 r2

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot, 22.04, alienware

I recently bought Alienware X15 r2, hoping to dual boot Ubuntu on a separate SSD (with windows 11) and leverage the GPU for ML work. I was able to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, the basic version however could not connect to the internet - 'no wifi adapters found' and ethernet is not working as well.

I have tried installing Ubuntu 20.04 - installation did not work.
Based on what I found on the internet, I believe that this version of Alienware has an Intel alder lake processor and wifi adapter which is relatively new and is not optimised yet.

Tried connecting external ubuntu compatible wifi adapters - did not work.

### Any suggestion/ recommendations would be highly appreciated. I am new to Linux - so not very experienced, please suggest.

Output for `lspci -knn | grep Net -EA3; rfkill list`

```
(standard input):00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
(standard input):   Subsystem: Rivet Networks Device [1a56:1672]
grep: EA3: No such file or directory
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -EA3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402766/no-hope-for-ax211-wifi-working-on-ubuntu-20-04

Comment: "an Intel alder lake processor and wifi adapter" : yes it's why I wait before updating my old desktop PC ; I am not even sure that alter lake processors are fully supported yet. See this question: https://askubuntu.com/q/1417437/188970.