# Intel 12th GEN CPU and Ubuntu

Tags: intel, 22.04

Is the 12th generation Intel CPU supported by Ubuntu, at least by 22.04 ? I mean by "supported" its two types of cores (P-core and E-core ?). It seems by googling the question that it is not yet supported.

Comment: Do you already own the computer? If so, try it - use a live usb session.

Comment: There are some reports (for example, https://www.tomshardware.com/news/intel-alder-lake-ubuntu-2204-lts-os-users-should-consider-a-kernel-update) that kernel 5.17 will support these CPUs better. You can test the performance differences yourself if you have such a CPU.

Comment: @FedKad  I don't have such a CPU. Only a very old desktop computer which will stop working eventually (I don't use Windows at all: it seems that Windows 11 can handle this kind of CPU). It is why I get some information. Thanks for the URL.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the soon to be released point version (at the time of this writting) will have good support for the new 12th gen Intel chips -- using the 5.19 kernel. This said, I also believe they are backporting more support into the 5.15 LTS kernel -- as time goes on -- for the 12th gen (Phoronix, 2022).