# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS no internet connection on DELL XPS 15

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, dell, xps

Just got a Dell XPS 15 the other day and dual-booted with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I managed to disable the ssd RAID and the bitlocker and successfully install Ubuntu, but I have not been able to connect to any networks and I don't have an adapter at the moment to check ethernet (since the only ports on this thing are USB C unfortuately). The only way that I have been able to use the internet has been through my iphone hotspot. I even bought a wifi adapter recently and for some reason when I plug that in it still gives no response. I fought with it for few days and tried a bunch of stuff but no luck. My XPS 15 uses a AX211 wifi adapter card and from checking with Intel (https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi) it should be compatible with my installation (I have kernel 5.15), but when I was looking around for drivers they don't appear to be available at this page (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html). As I was investigating, I found this article ([No hope for AX211 wifi working on ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402766/no-hope-for-ax211-wifi-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)) which described a nearly identical issue as to what I am facing, however I was unable to find the .deb file that he used and it seems like the file he mentions is for Ubuntu 22.04, not 20.04, and it uses a kernel higher that 5.15 (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/backport-iwlwifi-dkms/9858-0ubuntu2). It was around this point that I came across this article (https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000193252/wi-fi-6e-not-supported-on-client-linux-operating-system) which left me feeling a little more discouraged. I spoke with a co-worker who also had an issue with their wifi drivers when installing ubuntu 20.04 and he had me run

```
sudo apt install linux-modules-iwlwifi-5.15.0-46-generic
```

but unfortunately that did not get me moving either.

Here is some terminal data for reference:

```
$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
   valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Intel Corporation
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 14.3
   bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: iomemory:620-61f memory:62871a4000-62871a7fff

$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f1] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4090]
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51e8] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0beb]
```

If anyone has any advice for this issue or is familiar with it I would greatly appreciate any and all advice feedback. I am a little out of my element so feel free to dumb things down for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try an oem kernel. I have Dell Prevcision 3580 with the same network card and kernel 6.1.0-1013-oem works with this card, although not very reliably.