# wifi adaptor not found in 20.04

Tags: iwlwifi

I am using dell inspiron 5420 with intel i3 12thgen. I have installed ubuntu 20.04 along with windows but not able to find wifi adaptor in Ubuntu. Not able to to find wifi.

Intel® Wi-Fi 6E AX211, 2x2, 802.11ax

```
lspci -nnk | grep -iA3 net
0000:00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:51f0] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:4090]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

please help me in this

Comment: Since there is a driver associated with the wifi adaptor (`iwlwifi`) it is detected. There's some other problem. Look at the network logs with the terminal command: `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the termiinal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Is there a reason that you installed a three year old version of Ubuntu on your shiny new hardware? I think you'd have better luck with 22.04 LTS. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: type "sudo iwlist scan"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No hope for AX211 wifi working on ubuntu 20.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402766/no-hope-for-ax211-wifi-working-on-ubuntu-20-04)