# Lost Wifi adapter after real-time kernel update - Need help fixing drivers?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, realtime

I am working on a Dell Precision 5770 laptop which has Ubuntu Jammy 20.04.3. I was able to install the realtime kernel using ubuntu pro `sudo pro enable realtime-kernel` and it worked fine. However, upon rebooting, I lose my wifi adapter. I've checked and disabled secure boot, as one guide suggested to do so, but it was not helpful in getting it to work. I also have tried backporting the driver but it was unsuccessful. I can go into more detail about that if anyone is curious or can help me successfully do that, if that's the solution. Running the following commands shows me the following:

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: iomemory:640-63f irq:16 memory:6491244000-6491247fff
```

Notably, this is missing a lot of the driver configuration information, the card serial, etc...

Here's some background for information

```
$ uname -a
Linux devrod-lap 5.15.0-1053-realtime #59-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_RT Fri Jan 12 20:29:00 UTC 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ lsmod | grep iwlwifi
iwlwifi               458752  1 iwlmvm
cfg80211             1011712  3 iwlmvm,iwlwifi,mac80211
```

```
$ lspci -k
0000:00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 4090
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

```
$ rfkill list wlan
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

enx4cd717671816  no wireless extensions.

enx0015ff280501  no wireless extensions.
```

I've been pulling my hair out for 4 days trying every solution from every forum I could find, re-installing Ubuntu fixes the problem, so I assume it's a kernel issue. I eagerly await someone to guide me to success.

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I just ran it and it returned blank.

Comment: Let's try to load it and see if there are any interesting messages: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Still blank. No Response. By the way I REALLY appreciate this help.

Comment: We need a full diagnostic report please. Start here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos

Comment: Here's the full output. https://pastebin.com/uMddf9UV

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402766/no-hope-for-ax211-wifi-working-on-ubuntu-20-04 Please notice it is your same 8086:51f0 device. I suggest that you try: `sudo apt update && sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms` and reboot. Any improvement?

Comment: It worked. In no uncertain terms, I 100% can confirm I did this exact thing in the past. For some reason, it never completed correctly, so I assumed I would be unable to do it. I thank you so very much for your assistance with this.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was using

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Thanks to chili555 for their invaluable help.

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working!!