# MSI Katana is not finding the SSD during Ubuntu 20 installation

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, 20.04, system-installation

I get a MSI Katana 15 recently, during the Windows 10 installation I had the same problem but for windows there is the driver online. Once that you extract the driver in the bootable pen drive it is possible to install it before windows 10 or 11.

Ubuntu 20 on the other side, looks like that there is no driver for this micron 2400 SSD. So it is not able to select it during/before the ubuntu installation.

I already tried to disable bitlocker, to disable fast boot, to format the partition (like empty volume, exFat and NTFS), disable secure boot on BIOS and tried to use this tag until initiate ubuntu installation (with different values that I saw online):

- file=/cdrom/pressed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=0
- file=/cdrom/pressed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=500
- file=/cdrom/pressed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper nvme_core.default_ps_max_latency_us=2000

PS: The GParted image is just finding the USB pen-driver (with 32gb) there ins't any other driver.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you updated UEFI firmware to latest available? And updated SSD firmware. What exact version of Ubuntu? You need a release that is newer than hardware to have latest kernel & drivers. If very new hardware you may need 23.10 which will be released in a week or so. see https://askubuntu.com/questions/1488382/boot-from-live-usb-on-pro-b550m-vc-wifi AskUbuntu only supports released/current versions, so you may not get help here until it is released.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that worked for me (I also have MSI Katana 15) is shutdown of Intel VMD Controller in BIOS (Advanced -> System Agent (SA) Configuration -> VMD Setup Menu -> Disable VMD controller). Driver for this micron 2400 SSD in Ubuntu seem to be okay, but in case of using the VMD Controller, the storage is accessed "through" it. But Windows you have to reinstall.

If it makes sense, Ubuntu 22 is installed normally even with "Enabled VMD controller".

---

Also (in the next step) you might have problems with Wi-Fi on your Katana 15 in 20.04 (there's Wi-Fi 6, which doesn't fit well 20.04). Just in case, I found the solution here: [ubuntu 20.04 LTS driver intel WI-FI 6E AX211 160MHZ](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1398392/ubuntu-20-04-lts-driver-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax211-160mhz), backport-iwlwifi-dkms_9858-0ubuntu3_all.deb should solve wifi problem.